# PHPUnit: error when including Predis\ClientInterface.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, redis, phpunit

I am adding record via browser in redis cache with predis class it added and no error getting.

When executing from PHPUnit I get the next error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: include_once(Predis\ClientInterface.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

However same application, same unit test,same configuration works fine in my colleague's machine.

Comment: how is Predis installed in your machine?

Comment: I have directory structure of Predis is D:\projects\predis and I have include  require_once 'D:\projects\predis\autoload.php'; in my application which will add autoload predis directory in my application.Same thing working fine in colleague PC but not in mine

Comment: are you sure the path is included? command line php.ini file is usually distinct from the web server one. Please dump the included paths from the test, using get_include_path()